# Javascript Regex to check if a string contains accented characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working on checking if a string contains accented characters. for example

```
hellohello  ---> return true
helloéèhello  ---> return false because the text contains accent characters
```

can anyone help me with the regex

thank you

Comment: Does this topic answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: For your information, accents are allowed in some email addresses (depending on the domain of the address), although it is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @vincent, **(a)** Is your need only to detect the presence of accented characters or also to extract them? **(b)** What is your motivation to use regex for this? Is a non-regex based solution OK for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want a regex based answer. But if that is not absolutely necessary, then here is how you can do detect it.

(*Disclaimer*: I am not familiar with European languages that have accented alphabets, so I may have missed some linguistic aspect here. Also, I am more familiar with Java and the JavaScript here may not be optimal.)

### ASCII

If your text is ASCII, then I know no other way than looping through the character array and comparing its ASCII value to see if it is one of the accented characters. You can loop through from `1` to `255` and print the characters.

The accented characters, as I see, start from `192` onwards. However, not all characters beyond this are, so you will have to compare against the right set.

Here is a ***pseudocode*** that shows what I mean. (I am not skilled at JavaScript.)

```js
/* This array has to be prepared by looking at all ASCII characters till 255. */
char[] accented = new char[]{ (char) 192, (char) 193, ... };
for( let c of Array.from( 'helloéèhello' ) ){
    if( isPresentIn( c, accented ) ){
        console.log( "Accented chars present" )
        break;
    }
}
```

### Unicode

If this is a Unicode text, there is an indirect way to do this using normalization of Unicode characters. In Unicode, accented characters are usually composite characters. So, you can **decompose** the character and check if it has a component greater than code point 256.

To understand it in detail, you may go through the description at https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html.

*This is not perfect, but will be a good guide for you to come up with a more complete design.*

**Decomposing in JavaScript:**

```js
'helloéèhello'.normalize( 'NFD' )
```

Eg, `é` decomposes into `e` and code point 768, `è` decomposes into `e` and code point 769.

Note the difference in the characters without and after normalization.

```
Array.from( 'helloéèhello'.normalize( 'NFD' ) )
(14) ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'e', '́', 'e', '̀', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

Array.from( 'helloéèhello' )
(12) ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'é', 'è', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check for emails check out the answer that alex suggested but if you just want to check the above two test cases here it is.

*Note this is not for testing valid email just some valid string*

```
^[a-zA-Z@._]*[a-zA-z0-9]$
```

`^` Starting with
`[a-zA-Z0-9@._] lowercase, uppercase, digits,` @`,` .`&`_`are valid characters meaning accent and other symbols are not valid`*`greedy select matching previous character sets`[a-zA-z0-9]$` ends with alphanumeric data.

**Example**

```
hello@gmail.com   ---> return true
helloégmail  ---> return false because the text contains accent characters 
hello1 -> true
test@ -> false as it should end with alphanumeric character
```